# Form Validation - Accepting values in a certain format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Using HTML, PHP, Javascript, mySQL.

Trying to confirm that user must enter time in this format "--:--" (ex. 01:30, 10:00 etc.)in a text field using numbers.

If it's entered in any other formats other than "--:--" it will ask user to enter in the correct format.

Instead of giving a pop up, it will show that alert/warning message right beside the text field, once the user hits the submit button.

It's received as string but I am saving it as 'Time' type in mySQL to reach my goal.

I could do the part where I could validate that the field can not be left empty but got stuck with this one.

```
function validateForm()

var time =document.forms["entrypage.php"]["eventTime"].value;
if (time==null || time=="")

  alert("Please Enter time in --:-- format");
  return false;
```

Now in order to achieve what I am trying to do I can put more conditions in the if clause but it doesn't seem efficient ( i.e `x!="00:01"||x!="00:02"||x!="00:03"...etc`.)

There are probably tons of ways of doing this but some guideline/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to look up regular expressions - here's a duplicate question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400822/javascript-regex-validate-time

Comment: @RobBaillie He is blocked at that part where he want to check for empty input value. Thats what I understood from his question.

Comment: @Konza That's not what I asked for but thank you anyways.

Comment: @smokedMeat I have edited my answer to include time checking part too.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking strictly about format, correct?  You don't care about whether or not it's a valid time value at this point (example: "99:99" would pass as "valid")?

Comment: @talemyn I do care about the correct value of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a full check (for both format and value), I would use this code:

```
var time = document.forms["entrypage.php"]["eventTime"].value;
var isValidTime = false;

if (time !== null && /^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test(time)) {
    var hourValue = parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);

    if (hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12) {
        isValidTime = true;
    }
}

return isValidTime;
```

To break that out, you basically have three checks:

- `time !== null` - is there a value (you probably also want to check for `undefined`)
- `/^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test(time)` - this checks to see if there are 4 numbers, with a colon (`:`) in between the 2nd and 3rd number, and limits the 1st number to 0 or 1, and the 3rd number to 0-5.  If you want to support a 24-hour format, change the first character check to `[0-2]`

Once you know that the value matches the correct format, then you need to check to make sure that the hour value is valid (after all "19" passes the regex check, but is not a valid hour value).  There are two steps:

- `parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);` - split the time into its two parts, and then retrieve the hours value, as an `Integer`
- `hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12` - check to make sure that value is between 1 and 12.  if you want to support a 24-hour format, change the second check to `hourValue <= 24`

So there you go . . . that code should both enforce the format **and** the validity of the entered value.

Answer (score 0):

put a required attribute to your input tag. That will check if the text box is empty or not.

```
<input type = "text" pattern='\d{2}[:]\d{2}' required>
```

To check for the correct time you can pattern attribute with regular expression

Here is the updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/shyamchandranmec/C8B8t/1/

Comment: @ Konza Thanks man. I think I do need to fiddle around a bit with RegEx.

Comment: **Note:** This only works for HTML5 compliant browsers that support the new form input attributes (which doesn't include IE9 or earlier).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use Regex.

Some doc / tutorial: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

I think this should work, but it's kind of uggly:

```
if(/[0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]/.test(time)){
    alert('correct');
} else {
    alert('wrong input!');
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it's working and answering your question, don't forget to accept the answer please.