# HTML - Custom input with minutes and seconds

Tags: html, forms, input

I'm trying to make an HTML input, where I can input up to 100 minutes and 59 seconds.

The input should be like the time input.

Is there somebody with an idea what i can do?

Comment: You could try and look at using Regex.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11400868/1662973

Answer (score 1):

Either you do some javascripting or start to use a framework. Not jquery can support you in doing that, but here are some jquery examples to start with:
http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could code the interface and interactivity yourself, since that feature doesn't yet seem to be implemented in browsers (from what Jukka K. Korpela has explained). I can try to help with the code if you are interested. Please post a comment showing your interest if you'd like me to help.

Answer (score -3):

The HTML way of doing this is to use `<input type=time>` with a `max` attribute. Assuming the desired minimum is zero, here’s the code:

```html
<input id=foo name=foo type=time min="0:00" max="100:59">
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=time) is still limited to WebKit browsers. The markup degrades gracefully to a simple text input field in other browsers, but you may wish to add JavaScript code to check the syntax of input in that case.

Comment: Max seems to be 23:59 here, unfortunately.