# How to set minutes in "numbers" input filed , it should only accepts 0 to 59 value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set an input field "number" as minutes section. I tried maxlength =2 and min and max value for that input field. But when Giving input manually, it accepts till 99. How to set it to max 59?

```
<input id="minutes" 
       name="minutes" 
       class="form-control ui-control del-keyup tr-ui-witdh text-center" 
       placeholder="00" 
       type="number" 
       min="0" 
       max="59" 
       maxlength="2" 
       onkeyup="getMessage();" 
       onclick ="getMessage();" 
       onchange="getMessage();" 
       oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) 
       this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength); "maxlength = "2">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - Custom input with minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713338/html-custom-input-with-minutes-and-seconds)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner . No I'm asking about the input field number which is different from that]

Comment: Try without maxlength. It should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```js
function getMessage() {
    var val = document.getElementById('minutes').value;
    if (val > 59) {
      document.getElementById('minutes').value = '59';
    } else if (val < 0) {
      document.getElementById('minutes').value = '0';
    }

  }
```

```html
<input id="minutes" name="minutes" class="form-control ui-control del-keyup tr-ui-witdh text-center" placeholder="00" type="number" min="0" max="59" maxlength="2" onkeyup="getMessage();" onclick="getMessage();" onchange="getMessage();" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength); "
  maxlength="2">
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", e => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  if (value > 59) {
    e.target.value = 59;
  } else if (value < 0) {
    e.target.value = 0;
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="minutes" name="minutes" class="form-control ui-control del-keyup tr-ui-witdh text-center" placeholder="00" type="number">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your oninput function, add this attribute to your input element:

```
onkeyup="checkRange(this, 0, 59)"
```

It will call the function *checkRange* after every digit. The function itself looks like this:

```
function checkRange(element, min, max) {
    if (element.value > max) {
        element.value = max;
  } else if (element.value < min) {
        element.value = min;
    }
}
```

It takes the calling element and the minimum and maximum values as arguments, so you can reuse it in other input fields (e. g. hours).

Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/8rgmo7wk/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/8rgmo7wk/7/)