# How to limit military time input with jQuery Masked plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery Timepicker alongside jQuery Masked plugin. Everything so far is working as expected. The user enters a time and it is formatted appropriately, and is then followed by a dropdown that the user can click to select the correct time as so:

**This is good:**

[image]

The problem is that I can enter in numbers larger than `23:59`, which would make for an invalid time format, like so:

**This is bad**

[image]

How would I use the Masked plugin to stop incorrect formats from being entered?

Comment: I would  take the colon out , because military time doesn't get a colon anyways , then you can use very basic validation to keep the number in the range you want with regex.  OR you can just put every valid option in the dropdown and then stop the user from being able to type completely

Comment: Can you use the [`input[pattern]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-pattern)?

Comment: but besides my suggestions there , I found many answers by googling "jquery validate military time" like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400822/javascript-regex-validate-time

Comment: @Scott Selby I considered the latter at first, but I need to have the minute steps increment by 1, which makes it a lot less user friendly if I remove the ability to type in the number. I'll give the first thing you said a shot, though.

Comment: so either you make two dropdowns , separated by a colon . OR one without a colon.  of course this could all work with the colon , but.... I was in the military and it's just a pet peeve when I se people writing military time improperly. it should look like "2400" , "1840" , "1200" , etc

Comment: Haha yeah personally I would prefer to write it in the correct military format, however, my boss's requirements have me provide it with the colon.